# Combinations Question with different committees being able to be formed

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A local council consists of 4 female members snd 3 male members. What is the number of different 3-member committees consisting of 2 female members and 1 male member which can be formed?

Comment: $18$. But since you did not elaborate on your attempt, I will not elaborate on the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that "n choose k", $\binom nk$, means "$n$ (available from which to) choose $k$".

How many ways to choose two women (to serve on the committee) from a pool of four women?

How many ways to choose one man to (serve on the committee) from a pool of three men?

Now multiply those answers.

Comment: You're welcome, user108104!